# does WiFi Assist of iOS 9 work when cellular data is turned off?

Tags: wifi, ios-appstore, ios

Cellular connection kicks in when the WiFi is weak, that's a nice feature in iOS 9: WiFi Assist.

I have on question, when WiFi Assist is ON. Does it cause me cellular data in the following scenario:

- WiFi Assist is ON
- Settings > App and iTunes Stores > Use Mobile Data is OFF
- Now, WiFi is good
- I am downloading a huge app
- ... so far so good
- suddenly WiFi goes weak ..

Does AppStore continues to download and consumes my cellular data, or just stops?

Comment: I dont see such option in IOS9 (iphone6), region Latvia. Maybe it is US-specific?

Comment: Go to Settings > Cellular and scroll all the way to the bottom, even past the long list of apps.

Comment: The option is inside Settings > Mobile Data > ... scroll to bottom

Comment: I have screamed through my cellular data cap and suspect that it uses cellular data when wifi goes weak even if cellular data is switched off,   have not done testing to confirm this.   I have switched wifi assist and cellular data of in meantime.

Comment: I am on the phone with Apple (15 min) and they cannot tell me what the threshold is in Mbs that engages Wifi assist. They say it is different in different places? Inside houses and offices it is most likely constant. What? Mbs are mbs. What a windfall for the carriers who I find (AT&T) not forgiving. Thanks Apple!

Comment: I'm not surprised AppleCare front line doesn't have details. Did you ask them to escalate to engineering and get you an answer? You can also file a bug report if you are a developer.

Comment: 1 hour of waiting on the line with several reps but Apple could not tell me the threshold Mbs that would engage the wifi assist.  They were going to communicate with Apple engineering who they said are not available by phone!  On hold until they answer.

Comment: Two things. My suspicion is that the algorithm doesn't go on a single trigger. And even if it does, they reserve the right to change it. When things escalate to engineering, you provide contact details and a follow up happens - typically in a week's time. Sometimes it can take a month or so to get an answer.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, which means that someone other than me can decide when they would like to increase revenue for their carriers.  Isn't this akin to developing work around exhaust emissions software? What are we coming to?

Comment: Those aren't my thoughts at all. I would phase in the boost as RSSI decreases and also check latency not bandwidth. Well instrumented data usage seems like a bad way for Apple to "hoodwink" consumers and remove control. Perhaps you're confusing Samsung's benchmark optimizing software with VW's stonewalling once caught "cooking the books" on their control software. Also, LOL carrier love from Apple.

Comment: I do not see it is a "phase in thing".  It looks like on or off and no notification of when it is on or off.  That is very troubling and word be troubling if it was in ANY system.  Apple or any device manufacturer NEEDS the carriers and this is a simple way to create revenue to a great number of customers who have no idea what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the off switch for mobile data will prevent the use of data across the board.

You won't get any benefit from turning on "assist" nor will you incur any downside or costs due to data usage.